# Finding the limit of $(1+1/n^2)^{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having trouble finding a way to get the limit of the sequence $(1+1/n^2)^{n^2}$.

I know that $(1+1/n)^n = e$ and the above seems to be a subsequence of $(1+1/n)^n$, so my guess is that it converges to $e$ aswell.

How can I go about prooving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show it is an extracted sequence by showing that every value $n^2$ lies in $\Bbb N$, and they are increasing with$~n$. By definition a sequence extracted from a sequnce $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of the form $(a_{i_n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ where $(i_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is an increasing sequence of indices (in$~\Bbb N$); this is the case for $i_n=n^2$, that is $(i_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}=(n^2)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, which makes you example apply. Moreover, it is a general fact that tor any converging sequence, every extracted sequence also converges and has the same limit.

Comment: Could you be so kind to provide how you would show it is an extraced sequence? I am finding it hard to do without referring to examples and writing something next to it.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n$ converges to $e$ then since $a_{n^2}$ is a subsequence of $a_n$ hence $a_{n^2}$ also coverges to e. We use the result that every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

take $m = n^2$ and let $f(n)$ denote the $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \lim_{m \to \infty} f(m) = e.$$